# Как все происходит на самом деле? (проекты)

Tags: c#, лицензирование, java, visual-studio

Вот мы с друзьями учимся программированию и придумали один проект, который в будущем захотим продавать. Так вот насчет языка С# или Java. Если мы будем писать на шарпе, то чтобы продавать свой проект нам нужно будет купить лицензию MVS (до этого будет DreamSpark,  да и вообще) ? т.е Java в этом плане будет предпочтительнее?

Comment: А что такое MVS?

Comment: Я не очень в курсе, но есть же еще [BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/ru/ru/ms-start/) с лицензиями на 3 года и MS Visual Studio Express

Comment: MVS наверно это и есть Visual Studio

Comment: Назовите, пожалуйста, вопрос как-то более чётко, например, "Обязательно ли покупать лицензию для проекта на C#?"

Answer (score 6):

1. Для обоих языков существуют как платные, так и бесплатные IDE. Для Java, разумеется, их больше, но и на C# тоже ко-что из бесплатного есть. Это Mono Develop и Express-версии Visual Studio.
2. Если вы хотите писать свой мега-супер-проект, в котором можно будет грабить корованы, и который принесет вам кучу денег, то вряд ли стоит мелочно жадничать и экономить на спичках.  Поверьте, [22 839,36 руб.](http://store.softline.ru/microsoft/microsoft-visual-studio-professional/) за 1 штуку VS 2012 Professional - это малая часть тех расходов, которые предстоят вам, если вы действительно когда-то станете разрабатывать какой-то проект.
3. К тому времени, когда вы научитесь более-менее профессионально программировать, может случиться всё что угодно. Поэтому вы слишком рано загадываете

Comment: Прлностью с вами согласен.

Comment: А не проще сэкономить 22 косаря и скачать IDE с какого-нибудь торрента?

Comment: А потом на скачанном IDE соорудить проект, затратив кучу усилий, который после продажи нескольких копий также появится на торрентах, верно?

Comment: >А не проще сэкономить 22 косаря и скачать IDE с какого-нибудь торрента?

Можно. Но выглядит как мелочное жлобство. Особенно учитывая, что 22 тыр - это максимум четверть месячной зарплаты хорошего программиста

Comment: хорошие зарплаты

Comment: @SoloMio: Если вы работаете на себя и делаете хороший проект, вы получите несоизмеримо больший доход, несчастные 700 баксов не играют никакой роли. Если вы работаете на кого-то, то лицензии — это его проблемы, и вам пофиг.